# scrolling menu panel scrolls even if mouse isn't over the panel - so other content on stage scrolls as well

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am not able to restrict this code to scroll only the front_mc and back_mc, in the front_mc are nested buttons that work and showing content on click - but the mouse-movement gets captured all the time so also content of the menu gets scrolled, when mouse is moved. please help me guys, I am not fit enough to deal with it.

```
root.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,f);
```

var t:Timer=new Timer(40,0);
t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,moveF);
function f(e:MouseEvent) {
    t.stop();
    t.start();
}
var speed:Number = .9;

function moveF(e:TimerEvent) {
    front_mc.x =speed*front_mc.x+(1-speed)*(stage.stageWidth-front_mc.width)*root.mouseX/stage.stageWidth;
    back_mc.x = speed*back_mc.x+(1-speed)*(stage.stageWidth-back_mc.width)*root.mouseX/stage.stageWidth;
    if (Math.abs(front_mc.x- (stage.stageWidth-front_mc.width)*root.mouseX/stage.stageWidth)<1 && Math.abs(back_mc.x-(stage.stageWidth-back_mc.width)*root.mouseX/stage.stageWidth)<1) {
        front_mc.x = (stage.stageWidth-front_mc.width)*root.mouseX/stage.stageWidth;
        back_mc.x = (stage.stageWidth-back_mc.width)*root.mouseX/stage.stageWidth;
        t.stop();

```
}
e.updateAfterEvent();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

unfortunatly, it doesn't change the behaviour :( but thank you very much for this hint

what it does & should do:
this front_mc is horizontally scrolling a menu if the mousesY is 90 and 250 (its row of buttons is longer than the stage) the buttons and their common timeline are nested as menu_mc inside the front_mc.

if I go sidewards over the menu and its scrolling left/right & I hit a button the content is drawn, but when I head back to the menu and it's scrolling, so does the drawn content, analogue to the menu (synched).
I must have organized it wrong.

front_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,f);
var t:Timer=new Timer(30,0);
t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,moveF);

function f(e:MouseEvent) {
if(root.mouseY > 90 && root.mouseY < 250) {
t.start(); }
else {
t.stop();
}
}
var speed:Number = .9;
function moveF(e:TimerEvent) {
front_mc.x =speed*front_mc.x+(1-speed)*(stage.stageWidth-front_mc.width)*root.mouseX/stage.stageWidth;
back_mc.x = speed*back_mc.x+(1-speed)*(stage.stageWidth-back_mc.width)*root.mouseX/stage.stageWidth;
if (Math.abs(front_mc.x- (stage.stageWidth-front_mc.width)*root.mouseX/stage.stageWidth)<1 && Math.abs(back_mc.x-(stage.stageWidth-back_mc.width)*root.mouseX/stage.stageWidth)<1) {
front_mc.x = (stage.stageWidth-front_mc.width)*root.mouseX/stage.stageWidth;
back_mc.x = (stage.stageWidth-back_mc.width)*root.mouseX/stage.stageWidth;
t.stop();

}
e.updateAfterEvent();
}

Answer (score 0):

**solved.**

since _root.gotoAndStop(); from AS1-2 got removed, the easiest way in Actionscript3 AS3 to reference e.g. a Button inside a mc to call content to stage is

MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop("Marker1");

I thought I don't have a Movieclip on the Main Timeline MTL, but it realy works, set it as the action for your nested buttons and you are free from surprises: like in my case

I nested the scrolling menu (front_mc) inside a mc on MTL and the content gets called on the mainstage, without being hijacked by my moving front_mc

Answer (score 0):

You use too much words and code. You can add simple if(hitTest) exception.